# Read and increment counter in file using Python 3

Tags: file, python-3.x, counter

I am writing a pastebin service using `Flask`.  For each request, I need to stash the data in say `/data/1191` and update `counter.txt` to now contain `1192`, not `1191`.

Can I do any better than:

```
import os

try:
    with open( 'counter.txt', 'r' ) as f:
        counter = int( f.readline() ) + 1
    os.remove( 'counter.txt' ) 
except:
    counter = 0

req_data = str(counter)

filename = 'data/' + str(counter)
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True) 

with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write(req_data)

with open( 'counter.txt', 'w' ) as f:
    f.write( str(counter) )
```

*(please note I have revised the code in light of the comments)*

Comment: python uses `try -- except` and not `try -- catch`; for reading/writing a file you might look up the `with` statement. and there may be better ways to write data to a file (json or something; but if it's just a counter... why not?). and maybe this question is more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Assuming that `try -- catch` *doesn't work*, this question does not belong on CR (in its current state). You might want to read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Simon André Forsberg: agreed...

Comment: He is right though, getting_some_ version that works and putting it on CR sounds best. I've just revised the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this may be a start:

```
req_data = 'someting'

try:
    with open( 'counter.txt', 'r' ) as fle:
        counter = int( fle.readline() ) + 1
except FileNotFoundError:
    counter = 0

with open( 'data/{}'.format(counter), 'w' ) as fle:
    fle.write( req_data )

with open( 'counter.txt', 'w' ) as fle:
    fle.write( str(counter) )
```